# Find the optimal ratio to maximize a multi variable equation given constraints.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Given some function, and given constant $K$:

$$f(x,y,z) = x*y*z$$
$$a*x+b*y+c*z=K$$

How would $a$, $b$, and $c$ be determined such that function $f$ is maximized?

My first intuition tells me to take the derivative of $f$ and determine where that is zero in order to find a maxima / minima. Frankly speaking, I am not well versed in Calculus so I would think that taking the partial derivative with respect to $f$ would cause the left hand side to be zero. That does not seem correct.

As a bonus, the real equation I am attempting to solve is this. Given $K$ and $batk$:

$$damage(katk,fatk,pcrt,kcrt,kdmg)=(1+katk+fatk/batk)*(1+pcrt*kcrt)*(1+kdmg)$$
$$a*katk/0.05+b*fatk/18+c*pcrt/0.033+d*kcrt/0.066+e*kdmg/0.05=K$$

I believe I could solve this equation once I understand the simpler case

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. Unless you meant you want the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ that maximize the maximum point of $f$.

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking for. I phrased part of my question poorly, after calculating $a$, $b$, and $c$, I could calculate the ratio between the three variables.

Comment: In that case, first, you must maximize $f$ with $x$,$y$ and $z$ as variables and $a$, $b$ and $c$ as parameters. Then you maximize $f(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ with $a$, $b$ and $c$ as variables, where $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ is the solution of the first optimization problem.